# gulp-angular-templatecache throwing error when piping angular templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gulp

I'm having some difficulty with gulp-angular-templatecache. I have a gulpfile with a task:

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
        return gulp.src(paths.angularTemplates)
                .pipe(templateCache())
                /*.pipe(gulp.dest('javascript/angular'))*/;
});
```

I'm not sure why but the following error is thrown when piping to gulp-angular-templatecache and throws:

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at templateCacheFile (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp-angular-templatecache/index.js:89:40)
    at wrappedMapper (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp-angular-templatecache/node_modules/event-stream/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:84:19)
    at Stream.stream.write (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp-angular-templatecache/node_modules/event-stream/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:96:21)
    at Stream.method [as write] (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp-angular-templatecache/node_modules/event-stream/node_modules/duplexer/index.js:47:39)
    at write (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at emitReadable_ (/home/vagrant/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
```

I'm not sure what problem this error is related to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you managed to figure this out? I just found the same issue on an older project. Updated `gulp-angular-templatecache` with no success

Comment: Yes, there was a newer gulp-angular-templatecache version which broke the it. Ended up specifying a specific version in the gulpfile

Answer (score 0):

there was a newer gulp-angular-templatecache version which broke the it. Ended up specifying a specific version in the gulpfile

Answer (score 0):

In my project this was caused by a folder name with a dot inside.
So, I had a folder called `folder_name.html` and had to rename it to `folder_name`.

(Using gulp-angular-templatecache version 1.9.1)